# Download or create VCF from Human Genome Diversity Project (HGDP)

Tags: vcf, variant-calling, data-download, human-genome

I can't seem to find HGDP data in VCF format.

Does anyone know where I can download it from?

Perhaps there a Snakemake pipeline for calling VCFs from this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are looking for the recently sequenced WGS data rather than the genotype data? If so, the different files can be found here: ftp://ngs.sanger.ac.uk/production/hgdp/hgdp_wgs.20190516/

Each chromsome has a seperate vcf file with a corresponding .tbi index file.

The gvcfs can be found here: ftp://ngs.sanger.ac.uk/production/hgdp/hgdp_wgs.20190516/gVCFs/

These files are more compressed and smaller in size than the regular vcfs.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much!

Comment: No problem. If you feel like this has answered your question, you can close it by clicking 'accept answer'.

Comment: Sure thing. When you upvote my question ;-P